# WebClient DownloadString not working in ThreadPool

Tags: c#, mono, threadpool, webclient

I'm currently have a project where I try to get information from the NZBIndex.nl API using a C# console-application.

My request looks like this:

```cs
using (WebClient c = new WebClient())
{
    var response = c.DownloadString("https://nzbindex.com/search/json?sort=agedesc&hidespam=1&q=Ubuntu");
    Console.WriteLine(response);  
    //...
}
```

This worked fine in my main function and when executing it in a manually created thread. But it throws errors when running the code snipped in a function that gets called by a ThreadPool like this:
`ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(CheckMethod, item);`

The errors that get thrown when running it with ThreadPool look like this:

```
Thread was being aborted.
  at (wrapper managed-to-native) System.Object.__icall_wrapper_mono_threads_state_poll()
  at System.Uri.GetComponentsHelper (System.UriComponents uriComponents, System.UriFormat uriFormat) <0x40a23510 + 0x00033> in <4e15bbae9d7043d8afd6cfd50bd9bd5a>:0 
  at System.Uri.GetComponents (System.UriComponents components, System.UriFormat format) [0x00072] in <4e15bbae9d7043d8afd6cfd50bd9bd5a>:0 
  at System.Uri.GetParts (System.UriComponents uriParts, System.UriFormat formatAs) [0x00000] in <4e15bbae9d7043d8afd6cfd50bd9bd5a>:0 
  at System.Uri.get_Query () [0x00041] in <4e15bbae9d7043d8afd6cfd50bd9bd5a>:0 
  at System.Net.WebClient.GetUri (System.Uri address) [0x00035] in <4e15bbae9d7043d8afd6cfd50bd9bd5a>:0 
  at System.Net.WebClient.GetUri (System.String address) [0x0004c] in <4e15bbae9d7043d8afd6cfd50bd9bd5a>:0 
  at System.Net.WebClient.DownloadString (System.String address) [0x00000] in <4e15bbae9d7043d8afd6cfd50bd9bd5a>:0 
  at (wrapper remoting-invoke-with-check) System.Net.WebClient.DownloadString(string)
  at DBErrorcheck.Program.CheckThread (System.Object o) [0x00039] in <cf4c719a35df4ff094732dd5a9e883e9>:0
```

Debugging it doesn't really help since the programm stops after executing the DownloadString

Comment: Please share a [mcve].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just found the answer for this issue while trying to make a minimal reproducable example.

This error seems to be caused when a thread in the ThreadPool is still running but the main already exits. I found this out because with a `Thread.Sleep(500)` it fixed for me.

I guess a better way would be to check if the Pools has any jobs left.

Comment: Or simply catch and ignore that kind of exceptions, as you already know they are harmless.